# detecting AR markers in the fisheye camera?

Tags: google-project-tango, fisheye

I am experimenting with using AR markers in my Tango app.  The example Java and C applications are great for getting this working with the color camera, however, I want to try this with the fisheye camera (for added field of view).

I tried the naive approach of simply changing the camera callback so that I was getting the fisheye image.  Then, I passed this into the function TangoSupport.detectMarkers.  This resulted in a TangoInvalid exception (presumably due to the arguments that I passed to the function being invalid).

Based on what I've tried thus far, it appears that the fisheye image is not support by the detectMarkers function.  Can someone connected to the project verify this?  I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Assuming it's not support by detectMarkers, does anyone have an idea of how to proceed?  I am currently streaming the fisheye camera data to my laptop where I undistort the fisheye image using some OpenCV code I wrote.  Using this undistorted image, I am able to quite successfully find April Tags (a bit different than the Tango's tags) in the image.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I never found an easy way to do this, so I implemented my own version by using OpenCV Android SDK to undistort the fisheye image and then using apriltags (ported over to Android).

Here is a link to my code if anyone is interested: https://github.com/occamLab/MobilityGamesAndroid/tree/master/cane_game